# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Getting this exception while running following program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pojo.Bill.main(Bill.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

Bill.java

```
public class Bill {
    public static void main(String s[]){
        Bill b=new Bill();
        b.getBillDetails().setBillNo(444);// line 20
        System.out.println("bill no "+ b.getBillDetails().getBillNo());
    }

    private BillAction billDetails;

    public BillAction getBillDetails() {
        return billDetails;
    }

    public void setBillDetails(BillAction billDetails) {
        this.billDetails = billDetails;
    }
```

In BillAction there is  getter and setter of billNo
How to resolve this.

Comment: What do you think this `b.getBillDetails()` does or should do? And why do you think so?

Comment: `billDetails` in the `Bill` is not initialized.

Comment: If the application expects an empty `BillAction ` whenever a new `Bill` is created, you need to initialize `BillAction` variable in `Bill`s constructor. You are getting NPE because variable `billDetails` is currently Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`billDetails` not initialized. and you are calling method on it. 
so whenever you are calling method on "null" you get null pointer exception

so do this,    `private BillAction billDetails= new BillAction();`

Answer (score 3):

You are no where initializing `BillAction` for `Bill` object. By default the instance variables are set to null. So calling a method on `BillAction` will result in `NullPointerException`.

You need to override the default constructor and make sure you initialize the `BillAction` attribute as well in that. Or simply initialize it as mentioned by Sanjay in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have default constructor and you are not initializing billDetails. so You will get null when you call getBillDetails()